# Is there server side session state associated with ASP.NET Identity cookies?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

When using the ASP.NET Identity `ApplicationCookie` authentication strategy two cookies are created when the user logs in: `_RequestVerificationToken` and `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`.

**Is there any server side session state associated with these cookies?**
If so is it possible to configure this identity session state's its location (InProc, custom provider)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_RequestVerificationToken is a CSRF token.  It contains a value that must match one of the hidden fields in the page.  There is no server side session state associated with this cookie.  [More info](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/09/01/prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-using-aspnet-mvcs-antiforgerytoken-helper/).

.AspNet.ApplicationCookie is a persistent cookie that contains the user's identiy and claims in an encrypted and signed format.  The data is stored in the cookie itself, not on the server. [More info](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/02/18/evolving-asp-net-appscookie-authentication/)